# i Need to take one element in result observale

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-observable

I want to retun only a valure:
in html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let valCorr of valueCall| async">
        <th>{{valCorr }}</th>
    </tr>
```

in ts

```
 valueCall:Observable<number[]>
    //this.studentService.getResult() return an Observable<number[]>
     this.valueCall:Observable=this.studentService.getResult().pipe(map(result=> result.filter(x => x>2)),take(1));
```

in my serivce

```
 getResult():Observable<number[]> {
    return of([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
  }
```

the result is not only one element take it seems doesn't work. anyone can help me?

Comment: getResults() is a service call or getting observable data from some other resource?

Comment: Given the signatures and code provided, you code does exactly what you described. It retrieves an array of numbers, filters for numbers larger than 2 (in your example 3, 4, 5 and 6) and emits exactly once. You then see these numbers in your result.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner i don't kniow why it show me more results

Comment: You use `ngFor`, so obviously you expect a collection (?)

Comment: yes! but If I use take(1) , I think must be one value returned or I'm wronging?

Comment: @Pico, take(1) not work in this way, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Hi buddy you do that with this approach use find instead of filter to get single value and then convert that single value to type array

```
this.valueCall = this.getResult().pipe(
  map((result) => {
    let a = result.find((x) => x > 2);
    return [a];
  })
);
```

Comment: i need to use take sorry

Comment: Man to use take you have to use from() instead of  of() operator and you will get one single which then needs to type cast to array understand your problem first

Answer (score -1):

[take](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) rxjs operator **not** get one element else only execute one time the observable and unsubscribe, you're looking for

```
map((result:any[])=> {
  const values=result.filter(x => x>2)
  //be sure there're at least one element else return null
  return values.length?values[0]:null
})
```

UPDATE: About "take" If we has an observable like

```
getResult():Observable<number[]> {
    return timer(0,1000); //return 0,1,2,3.... each second
}
```

If we use pipe(take(1))

```
getResult().pipe(take(1))
```

When receive the first value (0) we unsubscribe -no more values are getting-

see a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i9kooa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: what about this?

map((result:any[])=> {
  const value=result.find(x => x>2)
  return [value]
})

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan, It's great use find!!. NOTE: in your way you return an array with an unique element (the `[` `]` create an array. if only want to return an element we simply return value or `map(result=>result.find(x=>x>2))`

Comment: @Eliso the point of using [] this is because they expected return type is array not value